# selecting rectangular area in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy rectangular area in Excel: two column by whatever rows there. Based on my research on the web, I wrote a line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Workbook).Range("c27", Range("c27").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Copy
```

It selects and copy only 2 by 2 square. Could some one help me to correct this code?
Thanks!

Comment: Real quick test - does this work `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Workbook).Range("c27", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Workbook).Range("c27").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Copy` ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with a 2 column x 4 row set of data in `C27:D31`, provided I change `Worksheets(Workbook)` to `Worksheets("Sheet1")`.  How have you declared and defined that `Workbook` variable?  Is `C29` a blank cell?

Answer (score 0):

For two columns:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range(Range("c27"), Range("D" & N)).Copy
End Sub
```